# How to move vector(points) coordinates, for a certain angle

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

I tried several things, but none worked as it should.
How to move vector(points) coordinates, for a certain angle that I calculated!

I calculated $\beta = 88.7^\circ$.
I'd like to expand/skew vectors $DA$ and $DC$, to get perpendicular vectors($90^\circ$)(in my case for $1.3^\circ$).
How to calculate that (**I need to get coordinates**).

After that I need to "move" the rectangle, to be perpendicular to the coordinate system (which is in the picture case the blue/black rectangle) 
[image]

I don't need the result, I'd like to know how this is calculated.

Comment: you can use the graham-schmidt process to change the basis to an orthogonal one. the linear transformation that does this is calculated by finding the coordinates of the new basis in terms of the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computations required here are lengths.

The only things that matter here are the lengths $|DA|$, $|DC|$ and what happens to the point $D$.

So assuming that the point $D$ moves to $D'$, then 
 the new coordinates will be $D'$, $C'=D'+(|DC|,0)$, $A'=D'+(0,-|DA|)$, $B'=D'+(|DC|,-|DA|)$.

Explicitly: If $A'=(x_{A'},y_{A'})$, $B'=(x_{B'},y_{B'})$, $C'=(x_{C'},y_{C'})$, $D'=(x_{D'},y_{D'})$, then

$x_{A'}=x_{D'},y_{A'}=y_{D'}-|DA|$,

$x_{B'}=x_{D'}+|DC|,y_{B'}=y_{D'}-|DA|$,

$x_{C'}=x_{D'}+|DC|,y_{C'}=y_{D'}$,

Comment: the D point can stay on the same position, it doesnt matter.

Comment: Then take $D'=D$.

Comment: How to calculate for example: C ′ =D ′ +(|DC|,0). Like Calculating vector(Xa-Xb),(Ya-Yb)?

Comment: If $C'=(x_{C'},y_{C'})$, then $x_{C'}= x_{D'}+|DC|$, $y_{C'}= y_{D'}$.

Comment: are this move formulas suitable only for perpendicular rectangle or have I just derived the wrong formulas for  A' and B'?

Comment: Yes to the first, and I have no idea what you are talking about for the second. The question states that you want to move the rectangle 'to be perpendicular to the coordinate system'.

Comment: Yes, you're right I want to move rectangle to become perpendicualar to the coordinate system but also if the rectangle is not perpendicualar itself I want to transform it to become one.
Can you please derive the formulas for A' and B', like you did for C' and that will be the answer to my question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you started with a rectangle, you'd first [shear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Shearing) with $k = \cos \beta$ and then [rotate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Rotation) it with $\sin = \frac{DC_Y}{DC}$ and $\cos = \frac{DC_X}{DC}$. As you are interested in the reverse procedure, simply take the inverse of this matrix. Note, however that this is not a unique transformation, satisfying your constraints.